# why is string.replaceAll misbehaving

Tags: java, string

I have always used `string.replaceAll()` without any problems.

But now I'm just stumped...

Here is my code

```
public static String getVersionName() {
    String versionName = null;
    versionName = "v"+packageInfo.versionName;
    versionName = versionName.replaceAll(".","_");
    return versionName;
}
```

versionName before replaceAll is `v1.0.4`

expected result is `v1_0_4`
actual result is either `v____` or `_____`
it varies for some reason, and is never the expected result.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because `replaceAll` expects a regex. You should probably use `replace` instead (which still replaces all occurences), since you only want to match a single character.

So using `versionName = versionName.replace('.','_');` on v1.0.4 will give you v1_0_4 as a result.

Comment: I want to replace 2 characters

Comment: @LenaBru it will still replace every occurrence of that character, it just only uses a single character as the thing it's trying to replace.

Answer (score 3):

It's happening because `replaceAll` uses regular expressions.

You need to escape the "." using "\\."

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll()` uses regular expressions, within which `.` matches **any character**.

Your options are to escape the `.` so it just means "." again, using `\\.`

Or, if you don't need regular expressions (You don't in this case), you should use `replace()` instead, which will be faster and you won't now have *two problems to solve*.

```
versionName = versionName.replace(".","_");
```